# Kubernetes SERVICE_PORT environment variable appears order dependent

Tags: kubernetes

I've added a second TCP port to my Kubernetes service, and have noticed that which port kubelet assigns to the `{SVCNAME}_SERVICE_PORT` [environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables) appears to be order dependent.

For example, if I declare my ports like this in my service:

```yaml
ports:
- name: example
  port: 9000
  protocol: TCP
- name: http
  port: 8080
  protocol: TCP
```

Then `FOO_SERVICE_PORT` will be assigned the value `9000`. But if I flip the order ...

```yaml
ports:
- name: http
  port: 8080
  protocol: TCP
- name: example
  port: 9000
  protocol: TCP
```

... then `FOO_SERVICE_PORT` is now `8080`.

Is there a way to force kubelet to pick a specific port to set into this variable so that it's not dependent on the order I've defined my ports in? That is, is there a configuration I can set so it always uses the "http" port (8080) as value it assigns to this variable, regardless of where in the list this particular port is declared?

Comment: In older Kubernetes versions, a Service can define only a single port. When they added support for multiple ports, by design they chose to put the [first port in the backwards compatible environment variable](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/envvars/envvars.go#L47).

Comment: That's useful to know (pity it's not documented outside of the code.) Is there a way to 'force' which port it picks or is it the case that it will _always_ pick the first and you just need to enforce the order your ports are listed?

Comment: I do not recommend relying on the env variables because when their value changes, it is not picked up by the container until the pod restarts. In the same sense, when you create the pod first and then the service, the pod doesnt know about the services at all from the env variables, until it restarts.

Comment: Yes, I don't rely on them either. Unfortunately there's another service which I don't own who's interacting with mine via the environment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older Kubernetes versions, a Service can define only a single port. When they added support for multiple ports, they chose by design to put the [first port in the backwards compatible environment variable](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/envvars/envvars.go#L47). There is no configuration that changes this behavior.

However, Kubernetes also sets `{serviceName}_SERVICE_PORT_{portName}` environment variables for named ports, so you can get the port number by port name. For example:

```java
FOO_SERVICE_PORT_EXAMPLE=9000
FOO_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP=8080
```